# No query results for model [App\WhatTodoModel]

Tags: php, laravel

I am newbie in laravel and I try to insert a data form a form having foreign key by using hide such as the code is mention below:-

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/WhatTodo/store" method="POST">

<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input type="hidden" name="task_id" value=" {{$what->task_id}}">
 <input type="hidden" name="work_id" value="{{$what->work_id}}">

 <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name"> Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
           {!!Form::select('name',$name)!!}
        </div>
 </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="work">work:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-5">

     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="work" value="">
    </div>
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">
      </div>
     </div>
    </form>
```

I have the controller with function:-

```
 public function create($id)
    {

      $what=WhatTodoModel::findorFail($id);
     $name=WOrk::lists('name','name');
     return view('what/create',compact('what','name'));


}
```

Comment: what is the error, the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't really told us what your issue is or what error you're getting, but my guess given the current question is:

Assuming you're trying to implement a resource route and resourceful controller, the `create` method is used to show a form to create a new object, not edit an existing one. The `create` method does not take any parameters, therefore `$id` will be blank and `WhatTodoModel::findorFail($id);` will throw an exception.

If you want to edit an existing record, you do that using the `edit` action.

For creating a new record, `create` shows the form, `store` saves the record.
For editing an existing record, `edit` shows the form, `update` saves the record.

Comment: i assumed too he wanted to do a create, but i think he's not getting the list he wants. I actually believe his method is only used for showing the form, not for processing it. Voted to close due to the question being unclear.

Comment: @Luceos Well, the title of the post is the error message you get from a `ModelNotFoundException`, which is thrown if a `findOrFail()` doesn't find a record. Combine that with the fact that the one method shown is `create`, and the action of the form is `store`, I assume he's using a resource route. Since resource routes don't pass parameters to the `create` method, I'm assuming that is the issue. That said, the question definitely needs to be fixed.